# Adding BackgroundImage to Home component using InlineCSS-Bootstrap-Vite-React-Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, vite, inline-styles

I'm trying to set a background image for my Home component, but I'm facing issues with the import. Here's my code:

```
import React from "react";
import image1 from '../assets/Backg.png';

export default function Home(): React.JSX.Element {
    return <div style={{backgroundImage : `url(${image1})`}}>
        <h1>Text</h1>
    </div>;
}
```

Whith that code, image is not rendering.

When I hover the import statment's route ('../assets/Backg.png'), it displays: `module "*.png"`,
If I Ctl+Click on it, two sources appear:

```
>node_modules\vite\client.s.ts
```

```
>src\assets\Backg.png
```

It seems to be using the first one.

I was able to use the image successfully by moving it to the /public folder and directly referencing it like `<div style={{backgroundImage: "url('/Backg.png')"}}>`. However, I would prefer not to keep the image in that folder.

I have tried the above code and also verified the image path, but the image is still not rendering as the background. I'm looking for guidance or suggestions on how to correctly import the image from the `../assets` folder and set it as a background image in my component.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late now, but on having this same issue I found the solution at: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

if you want to add background-image to your components, you should add "?url" at the end of your component path and it should work.